# How to get count values for multiple values in one column

Tags: sql

My data is like this

```
Name Values
A    Val1
A    Val1
A    Val2
A    Val2   
A    Val2
B    Val1
B    Val2
```

I want to ouput my data is this way

```
Name Val1Count Val2Count
A    2         3
B    1         1
```

I can get the Name and count(*) for Val1 with this query.

```
select [Name],count(*) FROM [table1]
where [values]='Val1'
group by [Name]
```

But I am not sure how to get the count(*) for val2 in the same row.

I tried doing this, but looks like this is not supported

```
select [name],@val1count= (above query for val1), @val2count = (above query for val2)
```

Please help. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called pivoting.  Some databases provide a PIVOT function.  However, you can also do this manually.

```
SELECT [Name], 
       SUM ( CASE WHEN [Values]='VAL1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Val1Count,
       SUM ( CASE WHEN [Values]='VAL2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Val2Count
  FROM [table1]
GROUP BY [Name]
```

Explanation:

- The `CASE WHEN ... END` gives each row a "boolean" value for whether or not the row matches your condition.
- The `SUM ( ... )` counts the number of rows which returned "true" (or 1).
- The `GROUP BY [Name]` consolidates the rows down to one row per distinct name.
- If you add conditions to a `WHERE` clause, the `CASE WHEN` will only see the rows matching your `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: If I had other clauses to add along with [values]='', Would they go in the Case WHen statement as well? These extra clauses are same for both the cases. Like product ='', Date=''

Comment: Since they are common for both cases, I added them after from [table1] where product= ''. But looks like its not working.

Comment: I edited my answer with an explanation.  Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: Actually. The original query with where clause was right. I missed a clause and that's why the numbers were not matching. Thanks so much for the help. :)

Comment: Btw. I used SUM instead of COUNT. Thanks